# How to Connect Azure Data Factory (ADF) with Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-data-factory, cicd

I want to connect an existing ADF project to Azure DevOps CI CD workflow. Any URL or resource will help

Answer (score 0):

You could check the links below:

1. [Continuous integration and delivery in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery)
2. [A Step-by-Step Process to Connect Azure Data Factory (ADF) with Azure
   DevOps](https://www.anblicks.com/blog/a-step-by-step-process-to-connect-azure-data-factory-with-azure-devops)
3. [How to Connect Azure Data Factory to Azure DevOps](https://blog.pragmaticworks.com/how-to-connect-azure-data-factory-to-azure-devops)
4. [Using Azure DevOps CI CD to Deploy Azure Data Factory Environments](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6510/using-azure-devops-ci-cd-to-deploy-azure-data-factory-environments/)